# Join table with another table and fetch and replace the values which are ';' seperated

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to join a table that has a column with data as a string and replace the values with the values from the joined table.

Tab 1

| ID | Name | Categories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Programmer | 1;2 |
| 2 | Analyst | 3;2 |

Tab 2

| id | Firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | kele |
| 2 | ajay | kashid |
| 3 | shubham | sharma |

I need a query that will fetch the "Id,name and categories" from the first table but in the form like:

| Id | Name | Categories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Programmer | john,kele ajay,kashid |
| 2 | Analyst | shubham,sharma ajay,kashid |

I have written this one but this gives only the first entry, not for all the entries

```
SELECT 
   sc.Id,sc.Application,u.u_LastName + ', ' + u.u_FirstName 'coeowner '
FROM
    Supportcentral AS sc 
outer apply [dbo].[FN_split](sc.CoeOwner, ';',0) s
 left join udcenter.dbo.[Users] u   on u.u_Login COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT in (select  s.item COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)
```

Comment: I would really suggest fixing your design here.

Comment: Mostly it's not a good idea to use comma-separated IDs to define the relationships between tables. As @Larnu suggested, it would be better to fix your design. Anyway, I proposed an answer to solve your problem, but with a correct design, it would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2017+, you may try the following:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.Name, 
       STRING_AGG(CONCAT(D.Firstname,' ',D.lastname),',') Categories 
FROM 
tab1 T JOIN tab2 D
ON D.ID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(T.Categories, ';'))
GROUP BY T.ID, T.Name
ORDER BY T.ID
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/D71BgUU1).

I think that you misplaced the comma in your posted output, if you want exactly the posted output use this `STRING_AGG(CONCAT(D.Firstname,',',D.lastname),' ')`.

For older versions of SQL Server you may use `for xml path` to simulate the `STRING_AGG` function as the following:

```
WITH CTE AS
  (
    SELECT T.ID, T.Name, CONCAT(D.Firstname,' ',D.lastname) fullname FROM 
   tab1 T JOIN tab2 D
   ON CONCAT(';', T.Categories,';') LIKE CONCAT('%;', D.ID, ';%')
  )

SELECT id, name, STUFF(
                       (SELECT ',' + CAST(T.fullname as VARCHAR(MAX))
                        FROM CTE T WHERE T.ID = D.ID
                        FOR xml PATH ('')
                       ), 1, 1, ''
                      ) Categories 
FROM CTE D
GROUP BY ID, Name
ORDER BY ID
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/eGVJwaXr).

Comment: STRING_AGG and STRING_SPLIT are not recognised in ssms.

Comment: What version of SQL server you are using? run this query to check `Select @@version;`

Comment: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "French_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
Getting this error

Comment: using ssms-18      .

Comment: SSMS is not the SQL server, *SQL Server = database engine; SQL Server Management Studio = GUI Administration Tool for working against the SQL Server engine*

Comment: I updated the answer to include a query for older versions of the SQL server, check the new query and update me if there is an issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query,

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT STRING_AGG(Name,',') FROM #Users WHERE Id IN (SELECT Value  FROM string_split(SC.Categories,';')))  AS Categories
FROM #Supportcentral    SC
```